# As3IsoLib not working

Tags: flash, apache-flex, isometric, actionscript-3

In the last few days I was trying to work with as3isolib, but still have a lot of problems:

When start debugging:

```
Class mx.core.Ifactory couldn't be found
```

With a little workaround I solved it, but:

```
Class IMXML couldn't be found
```

Everytime you solve an error, another is ready to make you crazy.

I understand that there are some problems with mx.core package in Flex SDK (I tryied with 5 different releases), but is it possible that nobody has never found a solution? is as3isolib about to die?

Unfortunately, for Flash/AS3, the only library with documentation and tutorials is this.

Where to learn isometric development in pure AS3 starting from tiles/arrays? Impossible to find clear tutorials all over the web.

Hope someone can help, I've done google searches for the last week.

As always, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can find multiple tutorial for isometric in as3, but the filmation engine use by as3isolib is not cover a lot. I can compile a project with the last version of the v1 library.

I use Flash Develop 4.5.2 and Flex SDK 4.6.0.

In my project settings, I link the as3isolib.v1.core.swc in the SWC Includes librairies parameters.

I add this class sample https://code.google.com/p/as3isolib/wiki/as3isolib_tutorial_001 and I can see a cube.

The Flex SDK 4.10 from Apache foundation doesn't work.

As3Isolib isn't maintain anymore by the author, so yes it's a dying library.

Comment: I'm actually using flex SDK 4.6.0 and as3isolibv1, but it doesn't work, all these problems lie in a conflict between mx.core package in flex and core package in as3isolib. 

So is there another way to develop isometric graphics? I also tryied to import tmx maps from Tiled, but nobody explains how to actually  display the graphics. The only solution seems to be drawing flat isometric artworks, losing tile system and coordinates, and that's not so useful in game development.

Comment: @Gio31290 If you've used Tiled before you might want to try [IsoHill](http://www.isohill.com/). This project hasn't been updated in a while either, but it's hardware accelerated(using MoleHill/Starling) and I've used it a while back for [a project](http://www.hirschandmann.com/2013/siemens-crystal/). In my case the  isometric angle wasn't standard, so had to extend Tiled with a custom view/renderer for my needs and similarly tweak IsoHill, but other than that IsoHill took care of a few headaches (like tmx loading, coordinate conversion, etc.)

Comment: I will surely try isoHill, I downloaded it a few days ago, but still need a tutorial/guide/wiki. Since I'm a beginner/almost intermediate developer I can't figure out how a library works only reading API documentations

Comment: I see, well I wouldn't recommend it as a beginner(not because it's hard, but because more documentation samples would help). Perhaps start with the simplest sample and work your way from there: try to load the simplest map possible, then gradually figure out how to perform the tasks you need (e.g. moving a character/object, moving the camera, etc.). Also an IDE with autocomplete and a browser tab with the generated documentation will be your main help sources. If you're really really stuck you can post specific questions here on SO. I don't remember if there ever was an isohill group/forum